# how to display alert when mouse cursor goes out of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display alert when the mouse goes out of window . Like http://ezwebsitebiz.com/testing-content/

i want to do this in jquery . how it can be achived

Comment: Use onmouseout event

Comment: i want event when mouse leave window

Comment: Just put a `onmouseout="jquery function()"` on your div. If need more clarification just create a jsfiddle and I will show you how to do it.

Comment: thanks @ Gagan Jaura your suggestion helped me a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

        jQuery(document).mousemove(function(event) {

            currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;

            currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

        });


jQuery(document).mouseleave(function() {

            var window_width = jQuery(window).width();

            var window_height = jQuery(window).height();



            if((currentMousePos.x < window_width) && (currentMousePos.y > 50))

                return true;

           alert(currentMousePos.x.toString());


        })
```

Replace alert message with your popup window or fancy box